# How to upload multiple image files to server in single request

Tags: android, image-uploading

I'm using xutils to upload pictures on Android. Single image uploading works fine, but multiple uploading fails. How to upload multiple image files to server in a single request?

Answer (score 0):

For the next time...

First, show a little part of your code because the other programmers can see your actions, second searches a little because it's probably the other people have the same problem, I say you this steps to preserve clean our forum, thanks.

Now, I know that the client (in this case is a device) never limited the information but all servers have a default limits of upload data, it's possible that you try to overextend this limit and the server ignore the post request... You need to know how many bytes you try to send and how many bytes you can receive with your server when you know this it's a good start point. When we know this, we can helps you!

Tell me if I can helped you and good programming!!